# checking if two values are the same

Tags: python, python-3.x

In my Python game I and making a dice rolling game, i got the part working where if you guess the number right it works, But i'm trying to develope a Higher or Lower part

But in my code if the value is 3 and you say higher it'll say you've won.

example `#debug (5)
Would you like to bet on higher or lower <h:l> <:   l
You won congrats!`

but I should've lost here instead of winning.

```
        elif user_nh == 'high':
        print(system_number)
        hiLo = str(input("Would you like to bet on higher or lower <h:l> <:   "))
        if hiLo == 'l' and system_number == 1 or system_number == 2 or system_number == 3:
            print("You won congrats")
            pa = str(input("Would you like to play again y/n :>     "))
            if pa == 'n':
                break
            if pa == 'y':
                continue
            else:
                print("You supplied a invalid response, quitting game.")
                break
        if hiLo == 'h' and system_number == 4 or system_number == 5 or system_number == 6:
            print('You won congrats!')
            pa = str(input("Would you like to play again y/n :>     "))
            if pa == 'n':
                break
            if pa == 'y':
                continue
            else:
                print("You supplied a invalid response, quitting game.")
                break
```

Comment: Don't link to code, post the relevant parts here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Put parentheses like this:

```
if (hiLo == 'l') and (system_number == 1 or system_number == 2 or system_number == 3)
```

However you had better to do like this:

```
if (hiLo == 'l') and (system_number in  [1,2, 3])
```

Answer (score 0):

Better yet, since you have already defined the higher and lower numbers, you might as well use them, like so:

line 39:

```
if hiLo == 'l' and system_number in lower:
```

line 49:

```
if hiLo == 'h' and system_number in higher:
```

Answer (score -1):

This line:

```
if hiLo == 'l' and system_number == 1 or system_number == 2 or system_number == 3:
```

Is evaluated something like this:

```
if   (hiLo == 'l' and system_number == 1): # Enter block
elif system_number == 2:                   # Enter block
elif system_number == 3:                   # Enter block
else:                                      # Don't enter block
```

So the `hiLo == 'l'` part is (currently) only affecting the first of your `system_number == 1` tests.  The code will enter the block irrespective of the value of `hiLo` if `system_number` is 2 or 3.

This is because the `or` operator has a [**higher precedence**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) than the `and` operator.

So you probably want something like:

```
if hiLo == 'l' and (system_number == 1 or system_number == 2 or system_number == 3):
```

or

```
if hiLo == 'l' and system_number in [1,2,3]:
```

or

```
if hiLo == 'l' and (1 <= and system_number <= 3):
```